# Failed to load resources with Jekyll on a Github page

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to create a website using Github pages and Jekyll. After finding one preferred template, [forking](https://github.com/st4ple/solid-jekyll) it, and running the website, I see that my website is not the same as the template.

I receive this error under "inspect element -> console":

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

A friend of mine said that Jekyll could not load the resource because this website is dynamic, whereas Github only hosts static pages.

Is it possible to host this template on GitHub?

Image of my website:

[image]

UPDATE: There seems to be missing a file titled `modernizr.js` which I could not find in the original repo. I created a new issue and hope the owners of the repo respond. This however is also shown when inspecting the original template. So this might not be the problem.

SECOND UPDATE: When I inspect both the original template, and my version of the website, under `Sources` I see that `assest/css` of the original template has two more `.css` files. My repo has those files, but my website does not seem to load them.

Comment: Please add a link to "your fork"

Comment: It says that I need more than 10 reputation to add a second link :( https://github.com/aulon/mjeshtri here it is

Comment: I mentioned in the comment of the first answer, but you are right, I should have posted it here as well. My url: https://aulon.github.io/mjeshtri

Comment: I saw it the moment I hit send.. :)

Comment: Have you tried serving the site from the `gh-pages` branch? Also, the `modernizr.js` you seem to be missing can be sourced from the parent repo's site's `source-code`

Comment: Yes the site is serving from `gh-pages` branch. Yeah I could not find that. I forked the exact repo, and I cannot find `modernizr.js`. Would you please help me locate it?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual URL or knowing if the screenshot is the local or hosted website, it's a bit difficult to say what's going on. If possible, you could send a link or clarify if the screenshot is local or hosted.

However, usually this 404 indicates a base_url problem. It is possible, that on GitHub you are hosting from a subfolder, while you don't do that local.

If this is the case, you can fix it by using a [baseurl](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/). You can add the base URL in _config.yml. Or you could set it at generation time by using:

```
--baseurl URL
```

Another option would be to use environments. Personally, I would create a simple shell script for generating for GitHub and use the --baseurl modified, but that's totally a matter of taste.

Re your friends answer, GitHub is indeed hosting the website static. Actually you are running Jekyll "dynamic" local, but it's also generating static content. Thus Jekyll serve does nothing else than putting static content to a folder, which is then served by web rick. There is no "real" dynamics like in PHP. It should also not have anything to do with your problem.

UPDATE: I was checking your sites repository and it seems there is no file called modernizerjs. https://github.com/aulon/mjeshtri/tree/master/assets/js
Is it possible you forgot to commit it?

**UPDATE 2:** This is the problem: https://github.com/st4ple/solid-jekyll/blob/master/_includes/css/style.css#L13-L14 The files are both imported, but this import does not respect the baseurl. You can either process this file by adding front matter and applying the base url, or you remove these two lines and link it from head.html directly. I would do the second one.

Comment: I apologize, I could not post more than two links due to my low number of reputation. Here is my url: https://aulon.github.io/mjeshtri/ 

I changed the content of baseurl to the name of my repository, as asked in the tutorial of the repo I forked. Still it does not work.

Comment: Thanks @surveyCorps. I see that other requests are working well, it's not the baseurl. When you create the site, can you check in your _site folder if the modernizer.js is there?

Comment: I added another comment, i can't see the modernizr file in your repo as well

Comment: First and foremost thank you for your time! I saw that in the console error, and I was searching for that file in the original repo, but it was not there. I opened a new issue on the original github repo.

Comment: Have you checked if the same error appears with the origianl template?

Comment: This is a great point! I just did and, yes the same error appears, but the original template looks fine. This is getting weirder. What could be the cause now?

Comment: Are these two missing CSS files in your Github repository?

Comment: yes they are. My repository is the exact same copy as theirs. Besides the `baseurl` part where I changed it to my repo name

Comment: Why do you think the CSS is missing? I can't see any failures in the console. Which one do you think is missing? Btw, you can download Modernizr here: https://modernizr.com/

Comment: because when I inspect my page, under `sources -> assets/css` two files are missing. When I inspect the original template, those files are there

Comment: I have bootstrap, fontawesome and style.css. What do you have?

Comment: the same, but the original one has those plus two more: `hoverex-all.css` and `prettyPhoto.css`

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The imports in style.css are not respecting the base url. You need to modify the template a bit, i described how

Comment: I followed your advice and even though the missing files did show up, my website still looks like a bad version of the original one. I am sorry it took so much of your time. I will pick another template from the internet. Thank you for your help

Comment: The only thing I see now is you should take care on sort order. when I recall correctly the imports were at the very beginning of the style.css. So you should move these files over style.css in the header as well, at ´the moment they are after

Comment: I changed the order. Still nothing